# Show that W is isomorphic to the subspace Y={$w+\alpha (w)|w\in W$} of V.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have this problem , I would appreciate any hints.

Let V be a vector space over a field $\mathbb F$. Let W be a subspace of V and let W' be a complement of W in V. Let $\alpha:W\to W'$ be a linear transformation. Show that W is isomorphic to the subspace $Y=${$w+\alpha (w)|w\in W$} of V.

Answer (score 1):

If you use $W\oplus W^{\prime} \cong W\times W^{\prime}$ you can write $Y$ as a set of pairs $(w,\alpha (w))$ and then there is almost nothing to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try to exhibit an explicit linear map $f:W\to Y$. Now can you prove that $f$ has an inverse, making it as isomorphism? Given a $y\in Y$, can you find a unique $w\in W$ such that $f(w)=Y$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Show the linear map $W\to V$, $w\mapsto w+\alpha(w)$ is injective.